# How to make Drag and Drop with following conditions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am working on a asset which uses drag and drop element. where fill in the blanks is displayed in drag and drop. options to be filled are draggable and blanks are droppable.

1. Only one drag is dropped over droparea when second time something is dropped then it will revert back to is original position.
2. filled options can be dragged from one droparea to another.
3. how to check in the last that all answers are correct or not.(or how to relate drag and drop)

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and what issues do you have with it? It might help if you make a MCVE showing your problem.

Comment: *"How to make Drag and Drop with following conditions"* - that is too specific to you. It is not likely to help anyone in future. So it's like asking us to code for you. Try generalizing the title and problem statement so that it doesn't sound like it (*something like fill-in the blanks using dnd*). Also, Make some effort, show us what you've so far and where you're blocked.

Comment: Also - *"how to check in the last that all answers are correct or not"* - What..? What do you even mean by *"in the last"*..? How do we know what are the correct answers..? What are the questions BTW..? are we supposed to find the correct answers via googling or something, and then code accordingly for you..? what you're expecting..! please go through [ask].